# Ninject: How to resolve collection from object type

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ninject

Just wanted to know if there is a way bind a type and resolve a collection. I dont know if Ninject can do this out of the box. I'm using MVC4 with Ninject3 so I have the NinjectWebCommon.cs where I register the services. There is nowhere I can get the kernel (I read that it was bad practice to access the kernel from elsewhere, but that can certainly be the solution to this).

For example, I'm having this class:

```
public class CacheManager
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Get<T>() where T : INameValue
```

I want to be able to send

```
CacheManager.Get<City>
```

and obtain the CityRepository class.

Comment: I think this may be a factory vs Ioc?

Comment: When you do Bind<IInterface>.To<TBar>() and Bind<IInterface>().To<TFoo>() injecting IEnumerable<IInterface>, ICollection<IInterface>, IList<IInterface> will result in you getting an instance of TBar and TFoo.
If you don't want to use Ctor or Property injection, use the IResolutionRoot interface: return resolutionRoot.GetAll<IInterface>().As<SelectListItem>();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing:

In NinjectWebCommon.cs:

```
        kernel.Bind(typeof(CacheManager))
            .ToSelf()
            .InSingletonScope();

        kernel.Bind<IDataListRepository<Locale>>()
            .To<LocaleRepository>();
```

In CacheManager.cs:

```
public class CacheManager: IDisposable
{
    private IKernel kernel;

    public CacheManager(IKernel kernel)
    {
        this.kernel = kernel;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAsEnumerable<T>()
    {
        var rep = kernel.Get<IDataListRepository<T>>();
        return rep.GetAll();
    }
```

I don't know if this is bad-practice (since kernel in theory should only be used in the initialization phase), but I didn't find any other way to do it.

If better options exist, please let me know.

Comment: I know I said this: 
 
One more thing, I'm in ASPNET MVC4, so I should not have direct access to the kernel –  Kat Lim Ruiz Aug 30 at 4:03   , but didnt find any other way

Answer (score 0):

Is it this you want to do? :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Ninject;
using Ninject.Modules;
using Ninject.Syntax;

public class Temp
{
    public interface ICity { }

    public class SelectListItem
    {
    }

    public class FooCity : SelectListItem, ICity { }

    public class BarCity : SelectListItem, ICity {}

    public class CityModule : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            this.Bind<ICity>().To<FooCity>();
            this.Bind<ICity>().To<BarCity>();
        }
    }

    public class CacheManager
    {
        private readonly IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot;

        public CacheManager(IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot)
        {
            this.resolutionRoot = resolutionRoot;
        }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Get<T>()
        {
            return this.resolutionRoot.GetAll<T>().OfType<SelectListItem>();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm unclear as to whether you have multiple implementations of T (ICity) or one implementation but several instances (like retrieving a list of city names from the database and creating one instance per name). The later you could solve by a this.Bind>().ToProvider(...) binding.

Comment: I think is not exactly what I need. Let me explain better: I want to have several entities like City, Country. Each has its own repository class as: IRepository<T>. So I want to be able to do something like Ninject.Resolve<City> and it should give me the impl of IRepository<City>. Do you know what I mean? I think actually my question should be worded as: how to create a factory in ninject?

Comment: One more thing, I'm in ASPNET MVC4, so I should not have direct access to the kernel

Comment: You might want to have a look at: https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory which simplifies factories. If named parameter ctor injection does not suffice, you will have to implement the factory yourself. The factory object will need to have IResolutionRoot injected to its ctor. The "create" factory method can build up all required parameters. Using resolutionRoot.Get<City>(parameters...) it can let ninject instanciate the City object.

Comment: If you would implement a spec test and upload it (entire project or solution), i'm sure it would be a matter of very few minutes to implement a sample for you.